# Android NewBie - facing issue for setAdapter ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I am totally new to Android and trying for Fragments for the first time.
I have used a ListView activity which I am converting in a fragment.
But somehow the ListView element retrieved by findViewById() is giving me null.
Can anyone please help me on this.?

Here is the code for ListView Fragment and I m getting error after I call setAdapter method.
Log value shows timeTrackerListView as null.I dont know why.!! :(

```
 package ray.kaushik.nasaapp;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class TimeTracker extends Fragment{
    private Time_Tracker_Adapter timeTrackerAdapter;
    private String TAG = "TimeTracker";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        timeTrackerAdapter = new Time_Tracker_Adapter();

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.time__tracker_layout, container, false);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ListView timeTrackerListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.time_tracker_List);
        Log.i(TAG, "timeTrackerListView-->" + timeTrackerListView);
        timeTrackerListView.setAdapter(timeTrackerAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note for future confused people: the code in the original question has been modified to put the `findByViewId` in the correct place, previously it was in `OnCreate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onCreate()` is called before `onCreateView()`. The ListView hasn't been inflated yet, this is why you cannot find it...

Simply move the current `onCreate()` code into `onCreateView()` or `onActivityCreated()`.

---

You should be able to set up your ListView in `onCreateView()` with little trouble by saving a reference to the inflated View:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.time__tracker_layout, container, false);
    ListView timeTrackerListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.time_tracker_List);
    timeTrackerAdapter = new Time_Tracker_Adapter();
    timeTrackerListView.setAdapter(timeTrackerAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

---

Diagram from [Developer's Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html):

[image: Fragment Lifecycle]

Comment: it still giving me same error. I have updated the new code and created new on onActivityCreated() method.

Comment: @RayKaushik Try using `getView().findViewById()`.

Comment: no luck..changes code to - 
`ListView timeTrackerListView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.time_tracker_List);`
anything I am missing..???

Comment: Hmm, I posted a different suggestion. If this doesn't work then double check the ListView's `id` in your XML.

Comment: This is the layout for ListView. Any error/suggestion for this.?
`<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/time_tracker_List"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    />`

Comment: No, that looks fine... Please post your LogCat, so I can see exactly what is happening. (Also if this fragment contains just one ListView, you can use a ListFragment instead.)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to get exact section in logcat..?
m nt sure whthr its corrct.
10-14 22:35:03.364: E/AndroidRuntime(708): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 22:35:03.364: E/AndroidRuntime(708): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ray.kaushik.nasaapp/ray.kaushik.nasaapp.NasaAppMainLanding}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-14 22:35:03.364: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
10-14 22:35:03.364: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)

Comment: You have the right lines but I need all of them. Simply edit all of the red error lines into your question, it should be between 10-30 lines.

Comment: thnx @Sam : the code changes suggested resolved the issue..shud have thought abt this..Thnx.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is you are trying to get the listview before you have set the view (`onCreate` is called before `onCreateView`)...  you need to move this

```
ListView timeTrackerListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.time_tracker_List);
```

and anything that references to the `onCreateView` method.

Comment: I moved the code to onActivityCreated() method..Code has been updated as well.